# codeigniter join query issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have query issue with two tables in mysql database. here is tables schema;

**course Table**

```
course_id   course_code course_name course_credit   course_description  lupdate
1           CS-02       Basics of Computer Science          3       
2           CS-03       Crash Course on Programming         3       
3           CS-04       C Programming                       4       
4           CS-04       Fundamental of Algorithm            4       
5           CS-05       Fundamental of Management           3       
6           CS-06       Computer Logics                     4
```

**course_prerequisite Table**

```
cp_id   course_id   prereq_id   lupdate
1          5           2    
2          6           3
```

and here is the display I want on my page;

```
course_code course_name                    course_credit    course_prerequisite lupdate
CS-02       Basics of Computer Science     3                NO  
CS-03       Crash Course on Programming    3                No  
CS-04       C Programming                  4                No  
CS-04       Fundamental of Algorithm       4                No  
CS-05       Fundamental of Management      3                CS-03 Crash Course on Programming   
CS-06       Computer Logics                4                CS-04 C Programming
```

can some body help me on the required output query in Codeigniter ?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` course_prerequisite with relationship based on course_id

SQL Query

```
SELECT course.course_code, course.course_name, course.course_credit, 
  IF(course_prerequisite.course_id IS NULL, 'NO', CONCAT_WS(' ',course.course_code, course.course_name)) as lupdate
FROM course
LEFT JOIN course_prerequisite ON course.course_id = course_prerequisite.course_id
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/338f2/1)

Hope, this CI query works.

```
$this->db->select("course.course_code, course.course_name, course.course_credit, 
  IF(course_prerequisite.course_id IS NULL, 'NO', CONCAT_WS(' ',course.course_code, course.course_name)) as lupdate", false)
  ->join("course_prerequisite", "course.course_id = course_prerequisite.course_id", "left");

$result = $this->db->get("course");

var_dump($result->result());
```

Comment: please add me on skype arif_shariati, it is development related

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("course");
$this->db->join("course_prerequisite", "course_prerequisite.course_id=course.course_id");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

If you just want some special fields change select method to:

```
$this->db->select("course.*, course_prerequisite.lupdate as CPLupdate");
```